# KafkaStreamTracing for flatMapValues

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-sleuth

How to work with KafkaStreamTracing for "flatMapValues". I looked into the KafkaStreamTracing but didn't find any suitable way to do that.

We have built a pipeline build on the kafka stream and need to enable distributed tracing using sleuth.

```
.mapValues(inboundDeserializer)
.filter(invalidaValuePredicate)
.flatMapValues(dataSplitter)
.mapValues(dataRule)
```

There is some mechanism for complex pipelines in KafkaStreamsTracing -

```
   * builder.stream(inputTopic)
   *        .transformValues(kafkaStreamsTracing.mark("beginning-complex-map")
   *        .map(complexTransformation1)
   *        .filter(predicate)
   *        .mapValues(complexTransformation2)
   *        .transform(kafkaStreamsTracing.mark("end-complex-transformation")
   *        .to(outputTopic);
```

I tried the above marker but was unable to log traceId and spanId.

Kindly suggest

Comment: ``` consistentStream.flatMapValues(ruleMapper).filter(subscriptionPredicate).filter(ruleFilter)
    .mapValues(dataMapper).to("outbound-topic"); ```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is enough to give some meaningful help. Could you please create a minimal demo app on GitHub (I can take a look)?
KafkaStreams are instrumented through Brave so that tracing headers get injected into the Producer and Consumer.

Comment: Thanks @JonatanIvanov .. let me put demo code on github